# Calculating an expression for the trace of generators of two Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose we have 
$$[Q^a,Q^b]=if^c_{ab}Q^c$$
where Q's are generators of a Lie algebra associated  a SU(N) group. So Q's are traceless. Also we have
$$[P^a,P^b]=0$$
where P's are generators of a Lie algebra associated to an Abelian group. We have the following relation between these generators
$$[Q^a,P^b]=if^c_{ab}P^c$$

I would like to know what we can say above the following trace. Is it equal to zero?
$$tr([Q^a,P^b]Q^c P^d)$$

Cheers!

Comment: From the cyclic property of trace we have $$tr[A,B]=0$$ for any matrices. Also $$tr([A,B]C)=0$$ just for symmetric matrices. Maybe these relation help!

Comment: In fact I want to know which conditions must be put on these Lie algebra generators to make the trace equal zero!